# Подгрузка формы из другой страницы + отправка сообщения на почту

Tags: jquery, ajax

Проблема с отправкой сообщения из формы, в момент подгрузки из другой страницы.

Получается отправлять только со страницы, где сама форма. Пробовал вместо `#form` прописать `.send`. Алертом выходит сообщение об отправке, но на почту ничего не приходит

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var btnClick = $('.link'); // кнопка, по нажатию которой будет подгружаться форма
    var btnCls = $('.close'); // кнопка закрытия формы

    btnClick.click(function() {
        if($( window ).width() > 768) { // данный метод будет работать только в полной версии сайта
            $('.send').load('ссылка на форму #form').fadeIn(4000); // подгружаем форму из указанной ссылки и ее контента
            $('#form').submit(function() { // устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
                var form_data = $(this).serialize(); // собираем все данные из формы
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "post.php",
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function() {
                        alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }

    /*
    function btnClose() {
        btnCls.click(function() {
            $('.send').fadeOut(2000);
        });
    }

    btnClose();
    */

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через `on();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width > 768) {
    $('body').on('click', 'form .link', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.send').load('ссылка на форму .posted');
      $('.send').fadeIn(4000);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
        success: function() {
          alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
          $('.send').fadeOut(2000)
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: попробовал, не выходит, после того как отправляю alert() не срабатывает и на почту так же ничего не приходит.

Comment: @daydreams покажите ваш php код